# Solutions to the integral $\int \frac {dx}{2\sqrt x (x+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am given a question to solve the integral $\int \frac {dx}{2\sqrt x (x+1)}$. When I substitute $x+1 = t^2$, I get the solution as  $\space \ln(\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt x) +C$; while when I substitute $x=t^2$, I get $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt x) +C$ as solution.

Are both the solutions correct or any one of them is wrong? If both are correct then can we equate the two solutions against each other (just a wild thought...)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try differentiating both?

Comment: one does not solve integrals but evaluates them.

Comment: A useful substitution would be $x=\tan ^2\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can't be the same, the first is unbounded while the second is bounded. At any rate, your second answer is correct.

For completeness, here's a derivation. Let $u=\sqrt{x}$, then $du=\frac{dx}{2 \sqrt{x}}$ and $x=u^2$. (This was a good choice precisely because the factor of $2\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator gets absorbed into the $du$.) So your integral is

$$\int \frac{du}{u^2+1} = \arctan(u) + C = \arctan(\sqrt{x}) + C.$$

Comment: So, does it means that substituting $x+1 = t^2$ would be wrong? If it is wrong then why can't we make that substitution?

Comment: @Ritu If you take $x+1=t^2$ then $dx=2t dt=2\sqrt{x+1} dt$. Now the $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator doesn't cancel, and so you have to rewrite $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{t^2-1}$ in the denominator, resulting in $\int \frac{t dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1} t^2} = \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1} t}$. This can be managed, but why bother?

Comment: Thanks Ian, I got your point..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $I = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{d(\sqrt{x})}{(\sqrt{x})^2 + 1}$